# What is the proper entry point for an angular application with separate files for controllers, services, etc?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have an angular application that has files separated by:

- UI router and initialization
- Controllers
- Services
- Directives

Before using webpack I had the router load first followed by the individual component files.  However, the other files don't depend on the router in the traditional sense to use its references - the router just needs to be loaded first.  Should I just create a completely separate `app.js` file and the import each file individually in the order of which I want them loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently an entry point can be an array of files like so

```
{
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    concatenated: ['es5-shim', 'es5-shim/es5-sham', 'es6-shim', 
    './vendor/polyfills.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

}